# How to pg_restore only tables in Rails schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, pg-restore

I have a pg dump file and a Rails app with empty tables.
I need to restore the dump ONLY INTO TABLES THAT ALREADY EXIST (which are those in the schema.rb).

The problem with the `--data-only --disable-triggers` options of `pg_restore` is that when referential integrity is violated, e.g. when trying to populate a child table before its parent records exist, the data isn't populated.

Alternatively using the `--if-exists --clean` options, it creates new tables in the database for everything in the dump file. (I realise now that `--if-exists` just means delete any existing table first before populating, it doesn't prevent new tables being created)

My reading of the pg_restore options is that this isn't possible. If so, is there a way to delete all the tables in the database that *aren't* listed in `schema.rb`? Either through the Rails app or from linux (SSM'ing into AWS EC2 connected to RDS)?
This would allow me to run pg_restore and then delete the extra tables after.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use "-l" and "-L" options of pg_dump and pg_restore, given the need to do certain parsing operations.

Comment: Ok thanks All looks a bit daunting to me. I'll try a ruby script to drop tables not in a whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this, and this is how I achieved it.  I took the dump file and created a sperate dump file just for the table I needed, and then imported it.

So the command to create the table's dump file

```
pg_restore --data-only --table=tablename fulldumpfilename.dump > onetablefilename.dump
```

The file extensions can also be `pg` I believe, mine was `.dump` so I kept that for the new file.  Also adjust the paths to match you files location.

Then you can import that table with the normal command

```
psql destdb < onetablefilename.dump
```

Might not be the best solution if you have a lot of tables, I only had a few and this allowed me to extract them out, import them, and also control the order they go in.

Comment: I have a load of tables yes. pg_restore behaves differently on me if I list the tables as -t options, so I have to stick with loading all tables for the moment.